# What does the second parameter mean in dblite's open

Tags: python, database, sqlite

As shown in the example in the link below, I am having trouble to figure out what the second parameter in open() is.. Can anyone tell me about this? Thank you

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scrapy-dblite/0.2.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Storage()` class constructor](https://github.com/ownport/scrapy-dblite/blob/master/dblite/__init__.py#L61) documents the second parameter as:

```
uri         - URI to sqlite database, sqlite://<sqlite-database>:<table>
```

So you name the full path of the database file (sqlite stores a database in *one* file), and a table name for the items to be stored in.

If you use an absolute path, it should start with an extra slash:

```
sqlite:///some/path/to/database.db:foobar
```

will open `/some/path/to/database.db` (creating it if it doesn't yet exist), and use a table called `foobar` in that database (again, creating it if it doesn't yet exist).

Comment: Thanks @Martin Pieters.. For scrapy project, what is the path supposed to be?

Comment: @Nabin: Anything you like; Scrapy doesn't care about where you store your database.

Comment: @Nabin: no, it doesn't. `sqlite3.connect` automatically will create the file, and the `dblite` project will automatically create the table if it doesn't yet exist.

Comment: Here is the problem. sqlite3 and dblite are different, right?

Comment: @Nabin: No, `dblite` *uses* `sqlite3` to implement it's features.

Comment: @Nabin: It looks as if the author meant for `dblite` to support other databases in the future, but as it stands right now it only supports SQLite.

Comment: I didn't know about 15 minutes.. :D @Martijin Pieters